# How to recover Facebook profile after it's been suspended? Error Message: "You can not turn your profile into a page"

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I used the migrate link [here](https://www.facebook.com/pages/create/migrate). When I took the steps in the process, picking friends and posts to migrate into the page, I clicked on the final step, I got an error message saying: You can not turn your profile into a page.

After that I was asked to upload a photo of mine to verify my identity. I did that, but it's been stuck on this message ever since.

[image]

Post image
I have tried to submit the disabled profile appeal form but it says my profile is not disabled.

I've also tried to email security@facebookmail.com and have not heard back at all. Not even with a message receipt.

It's been a few hours now, but I am seriously worried because this is causing me to lose some valuable time with my prospects.

I have some 4k friends on Facebook and I use it for business purposes, so it' a major disruption for my business as I have 10s of people messaging me for advice every day and a lot of them convert into clients.

Is there any other way I can expedite this?

Answer (score 0):

I sent multiple messages to Facebook via the "report a problem" option by logging in to another account.

Happy to report that my profile has been recovered,  I have gained back access to my profile .

I can log back in and and all my content is still there. It was after about 26 hours since the issue occurred.